# Mongoose - String included in strings array property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model which looks something like that :

> {
>     included : ['abc','bcd','c']
>   }

The Schema lookes like that:

> new Schema({ included : [String] });

Now I want to make a query that will find all the elemets in the collection where all the strings in the 'included' array contained a dynamic string. In this example to document will be in the results if the dynamic string is 'abcd' because all the string are included in it.

But if my dynamic string will be 'abdc' it won't be a reuslt of my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator as below,

Note: `included` is considered as a field in your model and you can fine tune the below as required.

```
var textToSearch = 'abcd';

Collection.find(
    { 
       $where: function() {
         var hasText = false;
         var included = this.included;

         for(var i = 0; i < included.length; i++) {
            if(textToSearch.indexOf(included[i]) > -1) {
               hasText = true;
            }

            if(hasText) {
               break;
            }
         }

         return hasText;
       }
    }
);
```

If required, you can change the `for` loop as below if you want to check all the string in the array,

```
     var hasText = true;
     var included = this.included;

     for(var i = 0; i < included.length; i++) {
        hasText = textToSearch.indexOf(included[i]) > -1;

        if(!hasText) {
           break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Added the schema to the question

Comment: currently what i get is : ' textToSearch is undefined '

Comment: You have to replace this with your text `'abcd'`.

Comment: thanks, the problem was i needed to hard coded my search string into the function